# Multiple pages in single repository?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

how to create multiple pages in a single repository in github?
Now for a single page, I am writing code in index.html
but how to create and share multiple pages links from the same repository is there any way like creating new directories or something?

Comment: How are you interacting with the index.html page?  Are you editing it directly in the github site?  You should clone the repository to your local computer and then create text files in your favorite editor (notepad, Notepad++, vim, emacs, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes just create files and directories

Check the doc at
https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#next-steps

> You can add more pages to your site by creating more new files. Each file will be available on your site in the same directory structure as your publishing source. For example, if the publishing source for your project site is the gh-pages branch, and you create a new file called /about/contact-us.md on the gh-pages branch, the file will be available at https://.github.io//about/contact-us.html.